# How do you plot the total summation of harmonics in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below manual method so as to plot the summation of harmonics. The below method is working fine.Please refer the image below.When the same thing implemented in for loop,it is not working as desired.The for loop is meant to take care of n number of harmonic values.Could any help me in this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# omega =2*pi

x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2000)
y1=np.sin(1*2*np.pi*x)/1
y2=np.sin(3*2*np.pi*x)/3
y3=np.sin(5*2*np.pi*x)/5
y4=np.sin(7*2*np.pi*x)/7
y5=np.sin(9*2*np.pi*x)/9
Y=y1+y2+y3+y4+y5 
plt.plot(x,Y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()

#Implementation in for loop is not working

def Harmonic(i):
    y = [] 
    for n in range(0,i):
        y=np.sin((2*n+1)*(2*np.pi)*(x))/(2*n+1)
        y += y
        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
```

[image: Harmonics]

Comment: Your loop is plotting y1, y1+y2, y1+y2+y3, etc. Just move the `plt` parts out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2000)
y = [0 for _ in x]

def Harmonic(i):
    global y
    global x
    for n in range(0,i):
        y += np.sin((2*n+1)*(2*np.pi)*(x))/(2*n+1)

Harmonic(5)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Or, if you want to have the function the make the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Harmonic(i):
    x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2000)
    y = [0 for _ in x] 
    for n in range(0,i):
        y += np.sin((2*n+1)*(2*np.pi)*(x))/(2*n+1)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

Harmonic(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the goal was to see the impact of increasing the number of harmonics in "real time", you should use `FuncAnimation`

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2000)
y=np.zeros((2000,))
l, = ax.plot(x,y)

def initPlot():
    ax.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
    l, = ax.plot(x,y)
    return l,

def Harmonic(i):
    y=l.get_ydata()
    y += np.sin((2*i+1)*(2*np.pi)*(x))/(2*i+1)
    l.set_ydata(y)
    return l,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, Harmonic, init_func=initPlot, frames=150, interval=100, blit=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example for you with a little bit of refactoring:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def first_solution(N=2000):
    w = 2 * np.pi
    x = np.linspace(0, w, N)

    y1 = np.sin(1 * w * x) / 1
    y2 = np.sin(3 * w * x) / 3
    y3 = np.sin(5 * w * x) / 5
    y4 = np.sin(7 * w * x) / 7
    y5 = np.sin(9 * w * x) / 9
    y = y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5
    plt.plot(x, y)


def second_solution(i, N=2000):
    w = 2 * np.pi
    x, y = np.linspace(0, w, N), []

    harmonics = [np.sin((n * 2 + 1) * w * x) / (n * 2 + 1) for n in range(i)]
    plt.plot(x, sum(harmonics))

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
first_solution()
plt.grid()
plt.subplot(212)
second_solution(5)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I've called first_solution to your working method and second_solution to your buggy one. Hope it helps