# Making Music with Python

Tags: python, audio-player

Trying to create some musical notes by combining harmonic series. Very simple code, but the audio turns up blank. Any thoughts?

```
from IPython.display import Audio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Harmonic(i,linComb):
    x=np.linspace(0,3,24000)
    y = [0 for _ in x] 
    weights = linComb
    for n in range(0,i):
        y += np.sin((2*n+1)*(2*np.pi*weights[n])*(x))/(2*n+1)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    return y

out = Harmonic(3,[0,2,3])
Audio(data=out, rate=8000)
```

[image]

Stuff I've tried:

- Changing the rate
- Manipulating the y-values
- Ensuring the harmonic function does indeed work
- Looking at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38953504/14217707) (same function, but still doesn't work)

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: `times` is not defined. Perhaps you meant to use `x`?

Comment: @SeanXie Typo. Replaced with `x`. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: When I run the code, I hear sounds. It is very weak, though.

Comment: @SeanXie Really? Hm ... any suggestions for amping it up? I don't hear anything, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @SeanXie This is certainly most terrific! Even though it comprises by removing the weights (which enable the linear combination of harmonics), I guess this is OK for now. If you'd like, you can copy-paste this as an answer and I'd accept it.

Comment: Cool, that is better. Pasting code-blocks into the comments is quite unsettling anyways :)

Comment: The highest-frequency component of your waveform appears to be about 5 Hz - which is *way* below the low end of the human hearing range.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah, interesting ... any modifications you would suggest?

Comment: You need to be passing significantly higher numbers to `np.sin()`.  I don't think that formula is quite what you intended - notice that you both multiply and divide by `2*n+1`, which cancel out.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah, but the first `2*n+1` is inside `np.sin()`, whereas the second is not. But I definitely see what you're saying. I just don't see how I should modify my `y+=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound generated by the code is audible but weak.

I have no experience in audio programming, but *some* type of noise resembling a loud beep can be generated by the following:

```
from IPython.display import Audio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Harmonic(i, weights):
    x=np.linspace(0,3,24000)
    y = [0 for _ in x] 
    for n in range(0,i):
        y += np.sin((2*n+1)*(2*np.pi*weights[n])*(x))/(2*n+1)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    return y

i = 1000
weights = [1000] * 1000 # Length equal to i

out = Harmonic(i, weights)
Audio(data=out, rate=8000)
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. Upvoted and accepted. If perhaps there could be a way to integrate the weights, that would be great, but no problem if not. Meanwhile, I'm tinkering with this on my own.

Comment: Sure, weights can be kept in. I have no idea what any of this means, but the code runs so long as `weights` has length `i`.

Comment: Ah, so it does! That's great. Thanks. Basically, weights allows you to construct *any* musical note, not just a square wave. Well, I guess this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)